# how to read data from the ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to get Unit_Price and Quantity to ActionResult Index.

any help appreciated

Model Product

```
public class Product
{
    public Product()
    {
        ProductsDetails = new HashSet<ProductDetails>;();
    }
    [Key]//[Required]
    public int ID_Product { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ID_Subcategory { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int ID_Category { get; set; }
    // [StringLength(50)]
    public string Product_Name { get; set; }
    //public byte Photo_Products { get; set; }
    // ID_Subcategory

    //public virtual ProductDetails ProductDetails { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ID_Subcategory")]
    public Subcategory Subcategories { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ID_Category")]
    public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ProductDetails> ProductsDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDetails> OrdersDetails { get; set; }

}
```

Model ProductDetails

```
[Table("Product_Details")]
public class ProductDetails
{
    public ProductDetails()
    {

    }
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //[ForeignKey("Product")]
    public int ID_Product { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName ="money")]
    public decimal Unit_Price{ get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public float Vat { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Gross_Value { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "money")]
    public decimal Net_Value { get; set; }
    // ID_Product
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel Producty

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Product> Producty { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductDetails> ProductyDetails { get; set; }

}
```

Controller Product

```
[Authorize]
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    // GET: Product
    private Context db = new Context();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var _product = db.Producty .Include(x => x.Categories)
                                   .Include(x => x.Subcategories)
                                   .OrderBy(x => x.Categories.Name_Category)
                                   .ToList();

        var _category = db.Categories.ToList();
        var _subcategory = db.Subcategories.ToList();

        var _price = db.Producty    .Join(db.ProductyDetails,
                                    sc => sc.ID_Product,
                                    soc => soc.ID_Product,
                                    (sc, soc) => new
                                    {
                                        Product = sc,
                                        ProductDetails = soc
                                    }).Select(soc => new {

                                       Cena = soc.ProductDetails.Unit_Price,
                                       Quantity = soc.ProductDetails.Quantity
                                    }).ToList();


        var _productDetails = db.ProductyDetails.Include(x => x.Unit_Price)
                                                    .Select(x => x.Unit_Price)
                                                    .ToList();
        var vm = new ProductViewModel()
        {
            //Categories = _category,
            //Subcategories = _subcategory,
            Producty = _product,
            //ProductyDetails = _price
            //ProductyDetails =_productDetails

        };

        return View(vm);
```

View Product Index

```
@model CRM_Hurtownia.ViewModels.ProduktViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product";
    ViewBag.active = "Product";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4 class="page-title">Product</h4>

@Html.ActionLink("Create Product", "Create", null, new { @class = "btn m-r-5" })

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover tile">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Categories)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Subcategories)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Products)
        </th>
        <th>
            Price
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantity
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var _product in Model.Produkty)
    {

        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _product.Categories.Name_Category)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _product.Subcategories.Name_Subcategory)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _product.Product_Name)
            </td>
            @*@foreach (var _cena in Model.ProductyDetails)
            {
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _cena.Unit_Price)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => _cena.Quantity)
            </td>

            }*@


            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = _product.ID_Produkt }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = _product.ID_Produkt }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = _product.ID_Produkt })
            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

I have tried many ways hence these comments in the code
maybe something of that will be useful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9Ev0.png)

Comment: which part exactly is giving you the trouble? you've shown us a bunch of code, but not told us what the problem is.

Comment: I don't know how to display in ViewModel price and quantity in action Index

Comment: More information. What exactly is going wrong with your implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Product` has a collection `ProductsDetails` in it's definition.

You are looping through your products collection here

```
@foreach (var _product in Model.Produkty)
```

but within this loop you then do the following

```
@foreach (var _cena in Model.ProductyDetails)
```

which to be honest doesn't make much sense, since it will just show all product details.

Instead, you should just show the `ProductDetails` in your `_product` object:

```
@foreach (var _cena in _product.ProductsDetails)
```

At least I think that is what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I noticed, that I trust is a copy over type-o, is on line one of your *View Product Index* is on line 1.
It should be:

```
@model CRM_Hurtownia.ViewModels.ProductViewModel
```

not

```
@model CRM_Hurtownia.ViewModels.ProduktViewModel
```

---

Another issue I noticed was that in your *View Product Index*, lines 15, 18, and 21 you want to use *DisplayNameFor* on specific properties. You have to define a name for them though...
So go into *Product View Model* and above each property, add the following:

```
[Display(Name = "Set Primary")]
```

It should look something like this:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
   [Display(Name = "Name for Categories")]
   public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Name for Subcategories ")]
   public IEnumerable<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Name for Producty ")]
   public IEnumerable<Product> Producty { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Name for ProductyDetails ")]
   public IEnumerable<ProductDetails> ProductyDetails { get; set; }
}
```

---

Another issue was with your foreach statement in the, *View Product Index*. There is no property in the VM that is *Produkty*, was it supposed to be *Producty*.

```
@foreach (var _product in Model.Producty)
```

If it was, now I am confused because it looks like *Producty* is using properties from *Model Product*, the *Product class*. If it is, then you need to either

**1)**

change the class in, *Model Product*, from, *Product*, to, *Producty*. Change lines 1 and 3 to be:

```
public class Producty
{
    public Producty()
    {
```

---

**2)**
or you can change the foreach in the *Product Index View* to:

```
@foreach (var _product in Model.Product)
```

and also change *Product View Model* to:

```
public class ProductViewModel
{
   [Display(Name = "Name for Categories")]
   public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Name for Subcategories ")]
   public IEnumerable<Subcategory> Subcategories { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Name for Producty ")]
   public IEnumerable<Product> Product { get; set; }
   [Display(Name = "Name for ProductyDetails ")]
   public IEnumerable<ProductDetails> ProductyDetails { get; set; }
}
```

if you do change it this way, then on line 9 in the *Controller Product*, you must change it to be:

```
var _product = db.Product .Include(x => x.Categories)
```

again, on line 17 your *Product Controller*, it references the *ProductyDetails* class. This class does not exist. I'm guessing you should have it as *ProductDetails*? Change it to this:

```
var _price = db.Producty    .Join(db.ProductDetails,
```

Also check the syntax in lines 31 and 38.

---

I would probabably go with the first option though:

> change the class in, *Model Product*, from, *Product*, to, *Producty*. 
>   Less work.

CHECK YOUR SYNTAX. I'm not sure if you have any other logic errors.

Comment: I had the variables in another language and translate variable names into English by Replace maybe something did not work properly. it's probably not a good idea